# Extracting <a> from Text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, titanium-mobile

I have an array which is getting text from a website using JSON parsing.

That text have an `<a>` tag sometimes at the end of text and sometime in between the text.

I want to extract that `<a>` tag.

Comment: Why not just do a `replace`?

Comment: Well I want to get that tag not to replace. Because it will act as a anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use regex, like:

```
var str = "test sdf <a href='www.google.com'>test</a> sdfsdf";
var anchor = str.match(/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/);
console.log( anchor[0] ); //returns <a href='www.google.com'>test</a>
```

Comment: Well I have another scenario now .. This is what i m getting in variable  : <a href="http://www.defconpaintball.com/hiring">Learn More</a> Now i want to get the link separately and the text separately too .. is it possible to extract both

Comment: yea, just doing console.log( anchor[1] ); should give you the text

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to extract, but a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) might be what you're looking for:

```
/\<a.*?\>/.exec('Hello <a href="foo.html">World</a>!')
```

Output:

```
["<a href="foo.html">"]
```